# Is it possible to pipe config file to hostapd?

Tags: pipe, configuration, hostapd

I use for some testing Raspberry Pis (Stretch) working as WiFi access points. Because i want to work with one global config file on many RPis i split `hostapd.conf` in 2 parts:

1. `hostapd.conf.global` - that describes almost all parameters of my wifi access point.
2. `hostpad.conf.local` - where SSID for particular RPi is saved.

Is it possible to join these 2 config files and send it as one to hostapd?
What i've tried, is to send:

`cat hostapd.conf.global hostapd.conf.local | hostapd -dd`  *(pipeline command)*

but as a result i get then help for hostapd.

I've tried also

`cat hostapd.conf.global hostapd.conf.local > hostapd.conf && sudo hostapd -dd hostapd.conf`

and this works but isn't the *pipeline command* equivalent of this?
Is my understanding of pipelining totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` operator connects the `STDOUT` from one command to the `STDIN` of the next command. This will only work with downstream commands that take `STDIN` as an input.

`hostapd` doesn't appear to have a parameter for this (many commands allow you to provide `-` as a filename to indicate that you want it to read from `STDIN`). Thus, you can't pipe configuration to it because it doesn't know how to consume that.

You could try:

```
cat hostapd.conf.global hostapd.conf.local | hostapd -dd /dev/stdin
```

and see if that works.

This is telling `hostapd` to use `/dev/stdin` as its configuration file... since you've piped your config files to `STDIN`, this should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use configuration management of some sort; this could be as simple as a `Makefile`

```
hostapd.conf: hostapd.conf.global hostapd.conf.local
        @cat hostapd.conf.global hostapd.conf.local > hostapd.conf
```

and then you type `make hostapd.conf` in that directory before running `hostapd`. On the more complicated side of things there's Ansible and other such softwares that scale up to larger number of hosts perhaps better than a `Makefile` does (with a correspondingly larger scale of things you have to learn about and deal with).